# Combining Primary Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a Database with 3 tables.

My question is how do I make the Primary Key for the ButlerSchedule table a combination of ButlerID, CustID, and ScheduleDateTime?

I beleive that I need a Foreign Key in ButlerSchedule that references the Primary Keys from the other two tables, but I'm unsure on how to accomplish this task. Thanks.

I'm using SQL-Server

**1. Butler**

```
ButlerID (PK, int, not null)

ButlerModel (varchar (70), null)

ButlerName (varchar (70), null)

ButlerType (varchar (70), null)

ButlerMadeOnDate (date, null)

ButlerActive (bit, null)

ButlerOutOfServiceDate (date, null)
```

The `Primary` Key is `PK_Butler_ButlerID`

**2. ButlerCustomer**

```
CustID (PK, int, not null)

CustFName (varchar (70), null)

CustLName (varchar (70), null)

CustAddress (varchar (70), null)

CustCity (varchar (70), null)

CustState (varchar (70), null)

CustZip (char (10), null)

CustCurrent (bit, null)

CustPITA (bit, null)
```

The `Primary` Key is `PK_ButlerCustomer_CustID`

**3. ButlerSchedule**

```
ScheduleDateTime (PK, date, not null)

PaidStatus (char (1), null)

CompletedStatus (char (1), null)

ButlerReview (varchar (max), null)

CustReview (varchar (max), null)

EnteredDate (date, null)

ModifiedDate (date, null)
```

The `Primary` Key is `PK_ButlerSchedule_ScheduleDateTime`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `ButlerSchedule` table schema.

```
ButlerID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Butler(ButlerID)
CustID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ButlerCustomer(CustID)
```

So now, your `BustlerSchedule` schema will look like this.

```
ScheduleDateTime (PK, date, not null)
ButlerID (PK, int, not null)
CustID (PK, int, not null)
PaidStatus (char (1), null)
CompletedStatus (char (1), null)
ButlerReview (varchar (max), null)
CustReview (varchar (max), null)
EnteredDate (date, null)
ModifiedDate (date, null) 
ButlerId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Butler(ButlerID)
CustId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ButlerCustomer(CustID)
```

If you already have the schema in place, then you will have to alter your table schema.

Use the below query to alter your table schema.

```
ALTER TABLE ButlerSchedule
ADD ButlerID INT,
ADD CustID INT,
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Butler_ButlerSchedule
FOREIGN KEY (ButlerID)
REFERENCES Butler(ButlerID),
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_ButlerCustomer_ButlerSchedule
FOREIGN KEY (CustID)
REFERENCES ButlerCustomer(CustID);
```

Comment: Would I use the ALTER TABLE clause to alter the schema?

Comment: Yes, you will have to update the schema using the `ALTER` command.

Comment: Could you post the correct syntax in order for me to do this? I'm still a little confused. I

Comment: Also, I want to Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Yes i got errors under the second ADD CONSTRAINT and the CustID in the FOREIGN KEY and the CustID in the REFERENCES

Comment: Looks like i had Butler instead of ButlerCustomer in the last line. I changed that to ButlerCustomer. Can you try with the updated query that I have specified in the answer.

Comment: in the references line?

Comment: Yes.. i have updated that. just try the query that is present there.

Comment: I'm still getting an error in line 5 saying that the syntax is incorrect near the keyword ADD

Comment: Try adding the constraints individually. Run just the first 4 lines. Instead of the comma, add a semicolon at the end.

Comment: I've tried that and it gives me the error: Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Foreign key 'FK_Butler_ButlerSchedule' references invalid column 'ButlerID' in referencing table 'ButlerSchedule'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: when i run the first 4 lines

Comment: Try this.  ALTER TABLE ButlerSchedule ADD FOREIGN KEY (ButlerID) REFERENCES Butler (ButlerID)

Comment: It says ButlerID references invalid column 'ButlerID'  in referencing table 'ButlerSchedule'

Comment: You will first have to add the ButlerID column to the ButlerScehdule table. For doing this use ALTER TABLE ButlerSchedule ADD ButlerID INT.  Once this query executes successfully, then try adding the foreign constraint as told before.

Comment: Will that combine ButlerID, CustID, and ScheduleDateTime for the primary key of the ButlerSchedule table? after the constraint query is run

Comment: I successfully ran the ALTER TABLE ButlerSchedule ADD FOREIGN KEY (ButlerID) REFERENCES Butler(ButlerID);

Comment: If you want the butlerid and the custid to be primary key in the ButlerSchedule table then you will have to mention it in the alter command. It will be ALTER TABLE ButlerSchedule ADD PRIMARY KEY (ButlerId). Like this you will have to add the custid as well.. this will make sire that the butlerid and custid are also primary keys apart from scheduledatetime.. once you are done with this then you can add the foreign key constraints.

Comment: Now that you are able to do this can you mark this as the correct answer and upvote ?

Comment: should i add a custid column to the ButlerSchedule table?

Comment: Yes. U will have to add it if you want the custid also to be the foreign key.

Comment: Also will there be any issues with the not null and null between the foreign keys and primary key

Comment: That depends on how you will be using your database.

Comment: Well this is beyond the context of the question.

Comment: I think your primary problem is solved. Mind accepting the answer and upvoting ?

Comment: yeah i can do that

Comment: Next to my answer, you will see a tick mark. You have ro click on it. This will then appear to all the people. Once you are done. At the same place you will have an up and down arrow to either upvote or downvote.

Comment: oh, if you could improve this table, would you add any specific tables that would avoid a problem like this?

Comment: Well i cant say that untill i know what is the end result that i would be trying to see. For now i can say that your tables look fine. Its just that you should have added the contraints at the same time you were creating your table schema.